# DateTime.Parse throws exception "not support in System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar"

Tags: c#, string, datetime

```
string formatString = "MMddyyyyHHmmss";
string sample = "20100611221912";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sample, formatString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

the specific exception thrown is:

System.FormatException: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Comment: Look at the the fmt and the sample:  `MM == 20`.

Comment: What date do you believe you have? Does it match the format you supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format should be:

```
string formatString = "yyyyMMddHHmmsss";
```

*(It can also be `"yyyyddMMHHmmsss"`, if it is 06-Noveber-2010)*

Considering your Date is `dt = {11/06/2010 10:19:12 PM}` (11-June-2010)

For your current format:

```
MMddyyyyHHmmss
20100611221912
```

MM can't be `20`, since `MM` stands for Month. So your code should be:

```
string formatString = "yyyyMMddHHmmsss";
string sample = "20100611221912"; 
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sample, formatString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Can’t we convert the string into the some other specified format than the original into DateTime?
I have DateTime string in “yyyyMMddHHmmsss” format and wanted to convert it to DateTime "MMddyyyyHHmmss"

Comment: @user2323308, sure you can, first Parse it to DateTime object and then use `DateTime.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss");`

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't mean to import the 10th day of the 20th month of the year 611, either your format string or your data is wrong. Did you mean to import with `"yyyymmddHHmmss"` ?